# Create exportable object or module to wrap third-party library with CommonJS/NodeJS javascript

Tags: javascript, module, node.js, export, twilio

I'm new to JavaScript and creating classes/objects.  I'm trying to wrap an open source library's code with some simple methods for me to use in my routes.

I have the below code that is straight from the [source](https://github.com/sjwalter/node-twilio) (sjwalter's Github repo; thanks Stephen for the library!).

I'm trying to export a file/module to my main app/server.js file with something like this:

```
var twilio = require('nameOfMyTwilioLibraryModule');
```

or whatever it is I need to do.

I'm looking to create methods like `twilio.send(number, message)`that I can easily use in my routes to keep my code modular.  I've tried a handful of different ways but couldn't get anything to work.  This might not be a great question because you need to know how the library works (and Twilio too).  The `var phone = client.getPhoneNumber(creds.outgoing);` line makes sure that my outgoing number is a registered/paid for number.

Here's the full example that I'm trying to wrap with my own methods:

```
var TwilioClient = require('twilio').Client,
Twiml = require('twilio').Twiml,
creds = require('./twilio_creds').Credentials,
client = new TwilioClient(creds.sid, creds.authToken, creds.hostname),
// Our numbers list. Add more numbers here and they'll get the message
numbers = ['+numbersToSendTo'],
message = '',
numSent = 0;

var phone = client.getPhoneNumber(creds.outgoing);
phone.setup(function() {

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    phone.sendSms(numbers[i], message, null, function(sms) {
        sms.on('processed', function(reqParams, response) {
            console.log('Message processed, request params follow');
            console.log(reqParams);
            numSent += 1;
            if(numSent == numToSend) {
                process.exit(0);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the function(s) you wish to expose as properties on the `exports` object. Assuming your file was named `mytwilio.js` and stored under `app/` and looks like,

**app/mytwilio.js**

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
var TwilioClient = twilio.Client;
var Twiml = twilio.Twiml;
var creds = require('./twilio_creds').Credentials;
var client = new TwilioClient(creds.sid, creds.authToken, creds.hostname);

// keeps track of whether the phone object
// has been populated or not.
var initialized = false;
var phone = client.getPhoneNumber(creds.outgoing);
phone.setup(function() {
    // phone object has been populated
    initialized = true;
});

exports.send = function(number, message, callback) {
    // ignore request and throw if not initialized
    if (!initialized) {
        throw new Error("Patience! We are init'ing");
    }
    // otherwise process request and send SMS
    phone.sendSms(number, message, null, function(sms) {
        sms.on('processed', callback);
    });
};
```

This file is mostly identical to what you already have with one crucial difference. It remembers whether the `phone` object has been initialized or not. If it hasn't been initialized, it simply throws an error if `send` is called. Otherwise it proceeds with sending the SMS. You could get fancier and create a queue that stores all messages **to be** sent until the object is initialized, and then sends em' all out later.

This is just a lazy approach to get you started. To use the function(s) exported by the above wrapper, simply include it the other js file(s). The `send` function captures everything it needs (`initialized` and `phone` variables) in a closure, so you don't have to worry about exporting every single dependency. Here's an example of a file that makes use of the above.

**app/mytwilio-test.js**

```
var twilio = require("./mytwilio");

twilio.send("+123456789", "Hello there!", function(reqParams, response) {
    // do something absolutely crazy with the arguments
});
```

If you don't like to include with the full/relative path of `mytwilio.js`, then add it to the paths list. Read up [more](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/modules.html) about the module system, and how module resolution works in Node.JS.

Comment: Thanks Anurag!  In the callback there at the bottom of your answer, what is `reqParams`?  I understand the normal HTTP callback args, but what are they for in this example?

Comment: @John - its the same callback from your example (`sms.on('processed', function(reqParams, response) ..`), which can be supplied by clients of the wrapper to keep things flexible. It is part of the `processed` event that this library emits after a SMS is sent. Looking at this [line](https://github.com/sjwalter/node-twilio/blob/master/lib/twilio.js#L226) in the source implies that `reqParams` is the request body, and `response` is an object of `Twiml.Response`.